# Audio Visualizer Using AudioKit and SwiftUI

Tags: macos, audio, swiftui, audiokit

Matt Pfeiffer posted a [tutorial](https://audiokitpro.com/audiovisualizertutorial/) "Build an Audio Visualizer Using AudioKit and SwiftUI", and posted his source code [here](https://github.com/Matt54/SwiftUI-AudioKit-Visualizer). Unfortunately, it doesn't compile. Another user posted a question describing the problem on the tutorial site, but it remains unanswered. That user points out a couple of simple changes that allow it to compile.

However, the [line](https://github.com/Matt54/SwiftUI-AudioKit-Visualizer/blob/2beafee52dc8cc8a2584c0d2853af82eaddba39f/Visualizer/Models/Conductor.swift#L86) `mic?.setOutput(to: micMixer)` in `Conductor.swift`
produces the fatal run-time error:

> Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type ‘AKMicrophone’

Any help in fixing this error would be appreciated.

Comment: Just remove the `?`. `mic.setOutput(to: micMixer)`

Comment: As Steven Cross' question on the tutorial website states, he tried removing the "?" and still got a crash with a lot of gibbirish of explanation.  So, removing the ? does not solve the problem.

Comment: I just received an email response from Matt Pfeiffer.  He will fix the original tutorial and source code in the next few days.  I will leave the question posted on Stack Overflow to point future audio-app developers to this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I commented on the tutorial, but will leave this here as well:

There have been changes made to the AudioKit framework since the tutorial was released that require adjusting how you setup the microphone.

I have rewritten the code to create this visualizer using AudioKit version 5 – the tutorial uses version 4, which depending on your version (4.x) could require one of a couple variants on how the microphone should be setup.

Please, see the following github repository, which uses AudioKit V5:
https://github.com/Matt54/AudioVisualizerAK5

I won’t list every change here between the projects as you can just download the project and run it / copy the boilerplate. However, some notable changes are that I have consolidated the two SwiftUI Views into a single View (FFTView) and I now use a callback from AudioKit’s FFTTAP in order to update the amplitude data for the view.

It’s also worth mentioning that with AudioKit V5, you can use the swift package manager to install AudioKit into your projects. See the “Installation via Swift Package Manager” section here:
https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit

Reach out if you have any more specific questions about this project.

Matt

Comment: I just downloaded Matt's code from GitHub and successfully ran it using Xcode.  It solved  the initial problem.  It looks like an excellent case study to explore how to use the analysis capabilities of AudioKit.  Matt, thanks for your prompt response.